# How can I use mock in my rails minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mocking, tdd, minitest

There are two classes, UserDevice(< ActiveRecord::Base) and NotificationAdapter.
In NotificationAdapter, I use AWS SDK, and UserDevice uses NotificationAdapter instance.
The Joint point is below,

```
protected def notificationAdapter
  @notificationAdapter ||= NotificationAdapter.new(self)
end
```

In UserDevice test, I want to make temporary NotificationAdapter mock for replacing the original NotificationAdapter, and use this mock only in the test.
But I don't know how to do, because this is my first case using mock in test.

I think it requires two steps below,

1. Make temporary NotificationAdapter class(NorificationAdapterMock) in test code.

   `NotificationAdapterMock = MiniTest::Mock.new
    mock.expect :setEndpoint, 'arn:testEndpoint'
    mock.expect :subscribeToAnnouncement, true`
2. Change notificationAdapter method of UserDevice to below,

   `protected def notificationAdapter
      @notificationAdapter ||= NotificationAdapterMock
    end`

But I don't know whether it is right or wrong. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to

1. `mock` your `NotificationAdapter`, so it doesn't fire the network but instead does something safe and easy
2. And also make sure that your adapter is correctly wired

Side note: Please, follow [ruby style guidelines](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide), method names and variables should be written with snake case and not camel case.

So, we may write it this way:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class NotificationAdapter
  def initialize(device)
    @device = device
  end

  def notify
    # some scary implementation, that we don't want to use in test
    raise 'Boo boo!'
  end
end

class UserDevice
  def notification_adapter
    @notification_adapter ||= NotificationAdapter.new(self)
  end

  def notify
    notification_adapter.notify
  end
end

describe UserDevice do
  it 'should use NotificationAdapter for notifications' do
    device = UserDevice.new

    # create mock adapter, that says 'ohai!' on notify
    mock_adapter = MiniTest::Mock.new
    mock_adapter.expect :notify, 'ohai!'

    # connect our mock, so next NoficationAdapter.new call will return our mock
    # and not usual implementation
    NotificationAdapter.stub :new, mock_adapter do
      device.notify.must_equal 'ohai!'
    end
  end
end
```

More information can be found in MiniTest's documentation on [mocks](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#mocks) and [stubs](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#stubs).

But let's don't stop here! I advise you to move your business logic out from your `ActiveRecord` models to a separate service class. This will have following good effects:

1. Your models become thinner
2. Feature is nicely encapsulated in its own class and obeys Single Responsibility Principle now
3. Your tests become blazingly fast, because you don't need to load Rails and can mock your model instead.

Here it is:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

# same adapter as above
class NotificationAdapter
  def initialize(device)
    @device = device
  end

  def notify
    raise 'Boo boo!'
  end
end

class UserDevice
# the logic has been moved out
end

class NotifiesUser

  def self.notify(device)
    adapter = NotificationAdapter.new(device)
    adapter.notify
  end
end

describe NotifiesUser do
  it 'should use NotificationAdapter for notifications' do
    # Let's mock our device since we don't need it in our test
    device = MiniTest::Mock.new

    # create mock adapter, that says 'ohai!' on notify
    mock_adapter = MiniTest::Mock.new
    mock_adapter.expect :notify, 'ohai!'

    # connect our mock, so next NoficationAdapter.new call will return our mock
    # and not usual implementation
    NotificationAdapter.stub :new, mock_adapter do
      NotifiesUser.notify(device).must_equal 'ohai!'
    end
  end
end
```

Have a nice day!

P.S. If you want to know more about testing in isolation, mocking techniques and general "fast rails tests" movement I highly recommend you Gary Bernhardt's [destroyallsoftware.com](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts) screencasts. This is paid stuff, but it very worths it.

Comment: Your answer2(with thinner model case) is the solution of my question. But a curious unsolved thing about answer1 is remain. I understand answer2 is better, but this is just for more understanding about active record test.   WHEN I write 'UserDevice' class in test code, it doesn't work with default methods with active record(maybe it does not inherit active record base).   and WHEN I write 'UserDevice  < ActiveRecord::Base' in test code, it doesn't work with validates of original UserDevice model.   Is there no way to make mock which works with active record things?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explained it before. You shouldn't write your real implementation inside test code, I put it here just for the reference, so you can grasp all code at once. If you already have `UserDevice` inside your `app/models` directory, you don't have to write anything in test.

Comment: Yes I have UserDevice inside my app/models directory, but it raise initialize error at 'UserDevice.new(user_id: 1, ...)' with 'wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)'.

Comment: It seems you build your model incorrectly. Maybe it doesn't load properly, it's hard to say without looking at your code. Have a look at this guide for testing in Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html or post another question on SO :). Also, if my code solves your problem, please, mark it as a solution. Thank you.

Comment: I found my mistake, I made a mock of UserDevice. So everything is work now. And your advices about snake style and SRP are very valuable because they are always in my mind. You  solved a lot of things in one answer!